# Shape with only one transparent border

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I'm trying to figure out how I could create a shape with only its right border transparent:

```
+ + + + + + + +
+
+
+
+ + + + + + + +
```

I would like to know how can I do that. At the moment I have just my basic shape which represents a rectangle but from this point I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#07000000" /> <!-- Transparent background -->


    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: use nine patch drawable for that kind of shape

Comment: Yea thanks for that. But actually I'm wondering if it's possible without this.

Comment: sure: you can: use `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class, but 9patch is the most simple way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea is just to hide the line you dont want to show. Since you have no option to specify it within the `shape` itself, you have to use `layer-list` and define negative padding to shift the rectangle so the right side is out of bounds. It is also better to have all corners rounded for not all of them are visible anyway. Try this code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#07000000" />

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow xml-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: It dosn't work. I just have one left border the top, bottom and right one are not visible. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Alex use nine patch drawable for that kind of shape